# How do I enable a Box Collider when a timer reaches 0?

Tags: unity, c#, input, gameobject, timer

I'm pretty new to Unity, and I am trying to enable a `BoxCollider` from another object when the timer reaches 0, using this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Testv2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;

    private BoxCollider Target;
    public float timeLeft = 30.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        Target = otherGameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
      timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            Target.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that the timer won't go down unless I keep clicking on the object. How do I enable the timer to start when someone clicks an object, and start counting down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem derives from counting down in the `OnMouseDown()` method. Let's take a look at the API:

> ### MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown()
>
> OnMouseDown is called when the user **has pressed the mouse button** while over the GUIElement or Collider.
>
> <sub>[- MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown() @ Unity API Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)</sub>

This means that you make a call to this method when you *press* the mouse button. Your logic performs one increment on the timer, and that is it. In the next frame, you are *still* holding the mouse button, but you have not *pressed* the mouse button - it was already pressed! As a result, the method does not call. For future reference, regarding input, there is a clear distinction between *pressing* a button, *holding* a button and *releasing* a button. That is irrelevant, for now. You do not want to have to continue holding your mouse button in order for your timer to work - you want it to just work straight away.

---

Instead of using this method to count down, you want to use this method to *start* counting down. We can easily do that by setting a `bool` to determine if we are currently counting down, and performing the count down in the `Update` method.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Testv2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;

    private BoxCollider Target;
    public float timeLeft = 30.0f;

    private bool countingDown = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        Target = otherGameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        countingDown = true;
        
        // If you want to be able to stop the timer by clicking the 
        // button again, replace the above line with
        // countingDown = !countingDown
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(countingDown)
        {
             timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            Target.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very informative and helpful, this worked great, I appreciate your help, thank you very much!